# Brand new Fujitsu Halcyon split system unable to keep temperature

Tags: hvac, mini-split

We had a Fujitsu split system installed, with 4 indoor units.

The issue I'm seeing is that the system is behaving in a way that I can only describe as "erratic".  We're observing a couple of problems, some manifesting on all the units, and some only on one particular unit in our bedroom:

1. Sometimes the units have trouble achieving temperature when heating: when set to 70F, they would only get to 66F and stay there indefinitely. Not obvious what could be going on.  At the moment as I write this, for example, my room is at 67F, while the thermostat is set to 72F.  It's 32F outside if it matters.  The device is has been unable to get to 72F for the past hour. The room is very modestly sized, I'd say no more than 300sqft.
2. One of the four units is in our bedroom.  If we set it to keep 67F overnight in heat mode, it would start blowing cold air with full power around 2 or 3 AM or so.  The HVAC installation person visited once post-install based on this report, refilled the heat exchange liquid and replaced something in the unit -- but the behavior wasn't fixed.
3. Sometimes when commanded to heat, all units would just blow a little bit of lukewarm air, despite the inability to achieve temperature.
4. Sometimes, the units would heat beyond set temperature, or would turn the fan active even when the temperature is far above its set point for heating.

All in all, it has been a very confusing experience. I would think that if you instruct your heater to achieve a certain temperature, that it does its best to do so.  And if you tell it to keep a temperature lower than the current room temperature, that it does not attempt to heat up the room even more.  Instead, we got a system with seemingly a mind of its own, and one that doesn't align very well with our ideas about home comfort.  I really would think that controlling temperature is such a well-researched problem that any unit you buy today would be able to follow instructions flawlessly.

What is going on here?

Worth noting, we installed a Honeywell smart thermostat next to each of the units to schedule their work, or operate them remotely.  Each unit also has a regular remote that came with the unit.  I observed that if both the smart thermostat and the remote are used, the device sometimes gets confused.  What un-confuses it is shutting down via both the remote and the smart thermostat, and then using only one of the two to control the unit.  (The smart thermostat can communicate with the unit, but supports fewer commands than the remote.)

Comment: Can you disable/disconnect/… the smart thermostats and see if the system starts behaving more reasonably? That would narrow down the issue a lot. Are the thermostats officially compatible with your aircon system?

Comment: You may be running into defrost, specifically defrost without a pan heater, which requires putting the head unit into cooling mode to remove frost on the outside unit - with a pan heater (resistance element on the outside unit) that's shorter duration, without one it's longer duration.  As for the temperature settings, Have a read: https://www.efficiencyvermont.com/blog/how-to/who-knew-8-ways-not-to-use-a-heat-pump

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- it shouldn't be blowing air *at all* during defrost cycles...

Comment: "thermostat next to each of the units" could be the problem. If the unit is blowing directly on the thermostat, the thermostat calls for heat, gets warmish air blowing on it, decides the room is now at the proper temp, shuts down. We had this issue in a commercial setting years ago - removed the airflow from near the thermostat & everything went back to normal. Try running an "extension cord" (of thermostat wire) _temporarily_ across the room to see if that fixes it. If so, make a permanent move.

Comment: With 2 controllers the things may be getting confused on who is in charge. If all the rooms are on 1 outside unit it may be undersized for cold weather an example of this would be 2small rooms with 9k heads and 2 big rooms with 1.8k heads that’s 5.4 but a common size is 5 or 4.5 both smaller than the total heat needed and is the inside head large enough for the cold temps? Some size for max savings and not for max cold. If the units are not proper sized for the conditions including the insulation of the home they may not be able to heat all rooms. Get in touch with them again & verify sizes.

Comment: disable-disconnect smart thermostats: yes I tried that.  My finding is that whatever the last command was sent to the unit, that's the "current" command, regardless of the device it came from.  On defrost:yeah, I'd expect no cold air blows.  "thermostat next to each unit" the thermostats are mounted outside of the air stream, and on the inner walls, thermostat mounting should be no factor. "2 controllers confusion" I tested and only *one* of the 4 units has this problem.  As for undersized external unit: when we run 1 at a time, only the faulty unit blows cold air.